# How to pass data from java script to html?

Tags: node.js

```
app.post('/result',(req, res) =>{
    const n = req.body.fname

    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/result.html', {n:n})


})
```

I want to transfer n to result.html file. My result.html file is below. This code is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p> <%= n %></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your html as below, by adding and id for the p tag

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Title</title>
  </head>
  <body>

    <p id="displayPtag"> <%= n %></p>

  </body>
</html>
```

Use the below code in your javascript

```
document.getElementById("displayPtag").innerHTML = n;
```